# gitlab only runs one job in child-pipeline

Tags: dynamic, gitlab

I have a gitlab-ci.yml that creates and trigger a child .yml

```
stages:
  - child-pipeline-generator
  - child-pipeline-trigger

generate-child-pipeline:
  stage: child-pipeline-generator
  tags:
    - GroupRunner
  script:
    - $(./generate-build.ps1) *>&1 > child-pipeline-gitlab-ci.yml
    - (Get-Content child-pipeline-gitlab-ci.yml) | Set-Content child-pipeline-gitlab-ci.yml -Encoding UTF8
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - child-pipeline-gitlab-ci.yml

trigger-child-pipeline:
  stage: child-pipeline-trigger
  trigger:
    include:
      - artifact: child-pipeline-gitlab-ci.yml
        job: generate-child-pipeline
    strategy: depend
```

The resulting yml looks like

```
build_1:
  tags:
    - GroupRunner
  script:
    - echo 'build_1'

build_2:
  tags:
    - GroupRunner
  script:
    - echo 'build_2'
```

But when executed only job 1 (build_1) shows up in the Downstream list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out the problem was the encoding of the powershell-output. Default encoding from powershell 5 is UFT16BOM and my reencoding to UTF8 resulted in UFT8BOM wich gitlab can´t handle properly. My sollution was to encode in ASCII.
What I can´t explain is why it was able to interpret the first job correctly, I thought that encodeing would result in an all or nothing outcome. Maybe the CRLF-CRLF after the first job caused the errror